# How to set global Clang flags?

Tags: c++, clang

I'm using Clang on MacOS. When I compile C++ with `clang++`, is there a way to specify `-std=c++17` without writing it every time? Is there some sort of a global `clang` config file?

Comment: Create a makefile?

Comment: May also try use CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alias c++="c++ -O2 -W -Wall -std=c++17"

You can add something like that to your bashrc or whatever shell you use.

Another thing that should work on MacOS, works on every other unix, would be to create a wrapper script in /usr/local/bin/. Assuming you have that in your $PATH. Otherwise the problem recurses to exetending your PATH.

```
% cat >> /usr/local/bin/c++ <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/c++ -O2 -W -Wall -std=c++17 "$@"
EOF
% chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/c++
```

The cat creates the file and the chmod makes it executable by all. Use the text editor of your choice if you don't understand that cat command.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a global config file or something?

Comment: More global than the users bashrc? /etc/bash.bashrc if you have that.